# Groovy Spock: is it possible to make "shared" a group of variables?

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a big group of variables in my spock test. First half of them are objects which need some serious effort to be created, and second one are the constants. I want to mark all these objects with **@Shared** annotation. But actually may be there is a better and shorter way to evaluate this task?

Placing 20 or 30 similair annotations one after one is not a groovy way, I suppose..

Comment: Can you show us? With just two or three objects, we can imagine the others.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a single context, so one `@Shared`

```
class Test extends Specification {
    @Shared context = [
                          one: new One(),
                          two: new Two()
                      ]

    def "Use of context"() {       
        expect:
          context.one.//
          context.two.//
    }
}
```